# Databricks: replicate columns

Tags: dataframe, databricks

Suppose I am having the following Dataframe :
YEAR    MONTH     Value 
2019    JAN       100
2019    JAN       200
2019    MAR       400
2019    MAR       100

And I do the pivot group by YEAR. ( df.groupBy().pivot()....)
YEAR      JAN      MAR
2019      300      500

But I also wanted to replicate the column of the Months through out the year even there are no data in that month ...

which means I would like to have 
 YEAR      JAN      FEB    MAR   APR   MAY  JUN  JUL AUG  SEP   OCT NOV  DEC 
2019       300      0      500   0    0      0    0   0    0    0   0    0

Thanks

Comment: anyone has the idea?

Comment: anyhas the idea ?